# Why does this C++ calculator keep showing me errors?

Tags: c++, numbers, calculator

So I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm making a multiplication/division calculator. Everything was working fine when it was just one operation but now its giving me a bunch of errors

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char operation;
    cout << "Select an operation devision(d) multiplication(m)" << endl;
    cin >> operation;

    float firstNumber;
    cout << "Please enter a number ";
    cin >> firstNumber;
  
    float secondNumber;
    cout << "\nEnter a second number ";
    cin >> secondNumber;
    
    float answer; 
        if (operation = m) {
        answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        }
        else if (operation = d) {
            answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            cout << "\nYour answer is " << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2) << answer;
        }

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Near the bottom where it's calculating based on the operation you put in, it says there these errors:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:19:25: error: 'm' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'tm'?
   19 |         if (operation = m) {
      |                         ^
      |                         tm
<source>:22:30: error: 'd' was not declared in this scope
   22 |         else if (operation = d) {
      |                              ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:19:25: error: 'm' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'tm'?
   19 |         if (operation = m) {
      |                         ^
      |                         tm
<source>:22:30: error: 'd' was not declared in this scope
   22 |         else if (operation = d) {
      |                              ^
```

Comment: Did you read the error messages?  Error messages exist to describe a problem.

Comment: `=` is assignment not comparison and `m` and `n` are not declared. The latter is an compiler error the first is a warning

Comment: you did not compare inside your `if` and `else if` you just making some assignments. To compare you have to use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: At a glance, you seem to be typing `=` when you mean `==`, and typing `m` and `d` when you mean `'m'` and `'d'`.

Comment: A character value is written in single quotes, like `'m'`. You might also want to check the difference between the two operators `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problems are in the statement `if (operation = m)` where you're doing assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`). This is also using the (non-existent) *variable* `m` instead of the *value* `"m"` or `'m'`.

Once you fix that in the multiplication section, you have the same problems in the division section. You're also only printing the output in the division section, but that's not really a syntax error, but a logic error. Move that outside the if statement to print the answer regardless of the operation chosen.

Comment: Wow thank you so much it's working perfectly now!